# How to use python to find matching data points in two arrays and return a third?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python, and trying to create a 3rd array from 2 others. I have two variables (X and Y) both related to depth, but not on the exact same depth points. I want to go through the depth values associated with X, and find ones in array Y that have a depth within 50cm of depth for X. Then return the depth and the Y value in a third array.

I thought 'for' loops might do this, but I don't know how.

Code:

```
A = np.genfromtxt('file.txt', names=True)
B = np.genfromtxt('file2.txt', names=True)

Depth1 = A['Depth']
X = A['variable1']

Depth2 = B['Depth']
Y = B['number']
```

A contains 806 lines, B contains 456.

I want to filter through A and extract the values (both depth and X) that correspond to within 50cm of each depth point in B, preferably into another array.

How can I do this? I have found things searching online that cover lists with the for loop, but not arrays.

**Sample Data:**

```
A = [(0.6, 1.463) (0.95, 1.468) (1.7, 1.465) (2.5, 1.502) (265.38, 1.715) ... (Depth1, X)]
B = [(0.58, 0.726) (0.93, 0.688) (1.69, 0.713) (2.48, 0.606) ... (Depth2, Y)]
```

**Sample Output:**

```
C = [(0.58, 1.463) (0.93, 1.468) (1.69, 1.465) ... (Depth2, X)]
```

Comment: Is there _any_ regularity to the depths? Or are they essentially randomly distributed integers?

Comment: Are you sure your "arrays" aren't actually lists? List is an array-type collection. Others include array.array, numpy.array, etc., but (unless you're using a very old Python or a very obscure array library) they should provide enough of the usual sequence API that the exact same code will work anyway.

Comment: The depths both increase, but not in regular intervals

Comment: Not quite sure about your C variable there. Would it not be better to have it in a list of dict? E.g. C = [{'B': (0.58, 1.463), 'A': [(0.6, 1.463), (0.95, 1.468)]}, ..., etc.]

Comment: @RichardNienaber I don't think so, I need the result as a usable array so I can run calculations on the values and plot them.

Comment: So you just want all the A tuple values in an array and not have to relate them back to B?

Answer (score 1):

```
depths = [a[(i-50. <= a) & (a <= i+50.)] for i in b]
```

**Edit:** in response to comment, that's not what's happening. `a` and `b` are numpy.arrays; `i-50. < a` evaluates to a flag array, with `1` in each position in which the value is > i-50., then `a[flagarray]` returns just the entries for which the flag array contains 1. The `&` combines the two flag arrays, in order to pull only the values of interest.  Hope that helps.

**Edit2:** something like

```
result = []
for i,n in zip(depth2,y):
    mask = (i-50. <= a) & (a <= i+50.)
    result.append((n, depth1[mask], x[mask]))
```

**Edit3:** it looks like, for each B depth, you want a single value - the label for the nearest corresponding A depth?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.6, 1.463], [0.95, 1.468], [1.7, 1.465], [2.5, 1.502], [265.38, 1.715]])
b = np.array([[0.58, 0.726], [0.93, 0.688], [1.69, 0.713], [2.48, 0.606]])

d1 = a[:,0]
x = a[:,1]

d2 = b[:,0]
y = b[:,1]

def find_index_of_nearest_value(array, value):
    return np.abs(array - value).argmin()

c = [(d, x[find_index_of_nearest_value(d1, d)]) for d,y in b]
```

results in

```
[(0.58, 1.463), (0.93, 1.468), (1.69, 1.465), (2.48, 1.502)]
```

This could be sped up by sorting the depth-arrays and walking through them in ascending order - but for less than 1000 values, this should be plenty fast enough.

Comment: `a` is being used both as an array and an individual variable here... what else is missing? (damned clever start though.)

Comment: Thanks Hugh, but won't this just return the depth in array B? I need it to return the Y variable that corresponds to that.

Comment: Hugh: What a difference a few details makes. Neat. :)

Comment: @user1499565: it would be *really helpful* if you could include some sample data, both input and output, so we have a better idea of what you want.

Comment: Is there any reason you use `&` instead of `and`?  AFAICT, there is no reason to use eager instead of lazy (short-circuit) calculations here.

Comment: @Tim S.: because `and` doesn't work to combine two numpy.arrays; instead it throws `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Comment: @HughBothwell, thanks but its not quite working, when I run the code of your Edit2, I get arrays within the results: e.g. [(0.436, array([70.55, 701.05]), (0.38, array([704.2])] which I can't use (which could be my lack of understanding!)

Comment: @HughBothwell - Edit 3 is what I'm looking for - thanks. But I get ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: @user1499565: when you load your data with np.genfromtxt, it returns an np.ndarray. You will have to convert this to an np.array for this to work.

Comment: @HughBothwell I did that, and still get the same ValueError

Comment: @HughBothwell could you please clarify what the 'd' is in your code in Edit3, please? Thanks.

Comment: @user1499565: `d` is each item in `B['Depth']`, iterated through by `for d,y in b`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the piecewise function. For instance, to find all items in an array greater than 4 and less than 6 would be something like:

```
n = numpy.array(range(10))
n = numpy.piecewise(n, [ n<4, n>6 ], [0, 0, lambda x: x])
n.sort()[::-1]
```

This approach doesn't filter the results and instead sets the unintended results to zero. This has the advantage of staying within  numpy which will result in better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
A = [(0.6, 1.463), (0.95, 1.468), (1.7, 1.465), (2.5, 1.502), (265.38, 1.715)]
B = [(0.58, 0.726), (0.93, 0.688), (1.69, 0.713), (2.48, 0.606)]

tolerance = 0.5 
print "\nTolerance: {0}\n".format(tolerance)

for b in B:
    print "B value: {0}".format(b)
    a_vals = [a for a in A if (b[0] + tolerance) > a[0] > (b[0] - tolerance)]
    print "  A values: {0}".format(a_vals)
```

Output:

```
Tolerance: 0.5

B value: (0.58, 0.726)
  A values: [(0.6, 1.463), (0.95, 1.468)]
B value: (0.93, 0.688)
  A values: [(0.6, 1.463), (0.95, 1.468)]
B value: (1.69, 0.713)
  A values: [(1.7, 1.465)]
B value: (2.48, 0.606)
  A values: [(2.5, 1.502)]
```

Comment: if I wanted to save the a_vals as an array/file instead of just printing them, how could I do that?